# Ios MFMailcomopseViewController Issue.How to get the messageBody from MFMailcomposerView after sending mail from In-App

Tags: ios

I Tried using some sample code but i Can't ..Please sombody Help With the solution...

The code which i tryed is

```
for (UIView *subview in [controller.view subviews]) {
    for (UIView *myview in [subview subviews]) {
        for (UIView *theview in [myview subviews]) {
            if ([NSStringFromClass([theview class]) isEqualToString:@"MFMailComposeView"]) {
                for (UIView *aview in [theview subviews]) {
                    for (UIView *thisview in [aview subviews]) {
                        if ([NSStringFromClass([thisview class]) isEqualToString:@"MFComposeScrollView"]) {
                            for (UIView *bview in [thisview subviews]) {
                                if ([NSStringFromClass([bview class]) isEqualToString:@"MFComposeTextContentView"]) {
                                    NSLog(@"%@", ((UITextView *)bview).text);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But Its not going inside the loop in this line...

```
if ([NSStringFromClass([theview class]) isEqualToString:@"MFMailComposeView"]) {
```

I searched in many sites...what i got is ,this code is broken in ios 6... BUT I am using ios 8.1....Please help me come up with the solution...

Thanks In Advance 
Nivetha

Comment: I think that you can't do it with a way that is accepted from Apple..

Comment: Thank you for your response Ondkloss...But ,What is the way to get the solution for my issue?

Comment: Is there anyother way to do this..